# GenyMotion Virtual Device opens and disappears immediately

Tags: android, android-emulator

I download GenyMotion Android Emulator with Virtual VM pack. Everything worked out well till the Virtual device download process. The virtual device was downloaded successfully but when I try to run the virtual device by hitting the play button, a small window pops-up that says Initializing virtual device and then Starting Virtual device. After a few seconds, it opens up the Virtual Device window but it disappears immediately. I've been trying to get GenyMotion running on my Windows XP PC for the last 3 days. I'm urging to get my hands on GenyMotion Android Emulator. Could anyone please help me?

PS: I've already scanned my PC with Anti-MalwareBytes and Avira Antivirus but the problem still persists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem (or at least the same symptoms). Try to start the VM directly from the Oracle VM Virtualbox (not via the Genymotion GUI). You should find the Virtualbox somewhere like "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe"

When you start the virtual device that way, you get at least a more or less meaningful error message that you can google for solutions. In my case, I had to enable Virtualization in my BIOS and update VirtualBox to the latest version twice. After the first try there was something wrong with the kernel drivers. So I restarted the setup and clicked "Repair" to re-install the VM drivers.

Also don't save the machine state when you close the VM. It's safer to always do a cold boot. As soon as you can start the VM from the Oracle GUI, you should be able to so with Genymotion. Only by starting the VM with Genymotion the virtual device gets connected to ADB and therefore can be used with your IDE.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I sent an email to GenyMotion team and they replied back with a new release of GenyMotion Android Emulator. I downloaded it right away and that problem was gone. Now I get the proper message why Android Emulator was not working on my Windows XP. The error was caused by the Video Card not supporting Open GL 2.0. My Video card had Open GL 1.4.0 installed. Now I've upgraded  the hardware and everything works fine now.