# can I scale genymotion emulator to "device real size"?

Tags: android, android-emulator, genymotion

I just started using genymotion and I really like it.

One thing that is frustrating me is that emulators take a lot of screen space and are contained within scrolling window.. which makes it less convenient to use

I tried to change screen resolution or look for some kind of option myself but with no luck

is there "scale to real device size" option like in sdk emulator?

[image]

UPDATE

---

when I start genymotion binary, get the following in the console

~/coding/genymotion$ sudo ./genymotion
Genymotion log file: /home/u238/.Genymobile/genymotion.log
Player log file: /home/u238/.Genymobile/genymotion-player.log
OpenGL connected to 192.168.56.101:25000
Port 22468 will be used for OpenGL data connections

The emulator shows up for about 5 sec.. black screen with white ui buttons on the right.. and then it disapears from screen

### UPDATE

[facepalm] to solve the vanishing emulator just install graphic drivers supporting opengl 2
[GenyMotion Virtual Device opens and disappears immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500108/genymotion-virtual-device-opens-and-disappears-immediately)

Comment: The emulator is supposed to fit the windows size. If you scale it down, the emulator's display is scaled down too. And there is no scroll window. Can you explaine more about the exact problem or add a screenshot to your question?

Comment: in my case when I resize the window containing the emulator.. it produces scroll bars.. emulator screen size does not change. I've added a screen shot showing what I mean. On the right you have a typical ldpi emulator with "scale to real device size" selected

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I get it.

You're not running the Genymotion player but Virtual Box. Try to run the `genymotion` binary (the one where you downloaded the templates) and to launch your VMs from it directly. It brings a lot of improvements.

Comment: your answer does answer the priamry question, so marking it.. any idea what is happening though with emulator vanishing?

Comment: What is the template your talking about?

Comment: The templates are the VMs you download from the genymotion service.