# GenyMotion scale to size

Tags: genymotion

For some reason I am not able to make my Genymotion player to scale to actual display.
I have look d at the post [can I scale genymotion emulator to “device real size”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18046482/can-i-scale-genymotion-emulator-to-device-real-size?rq=1) and it was not much of a help to me because I am already using the player. All I can do right now is re-size the window, but that does not give me an accurate display size. I am on a windows 7 if it matters.Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is sadly no way to resize 1:1 genymotion yet.

But there is a workaround: when it starts, the default size will be 1:1. 
You could stop and restart it, and never resize it.

There is a limitation tho, if the VM size is bigger than your screen size, genymotion will shrink the VM window.

Adding another screen may help (or not, depending on os/version) to get a bigger virtual screen size, allowing to display big xxhdpi with 1:1 size.

Answer (score 0):

Just increase the size of dpi for device  from Genymotion . first select the device and press ctlr+R and increase as you want . i have done this my problem was solved