# genymotion player.exe stopped working

Tags: android, virtualbox, genymotion

when I try to start genymotion android emulator it gives me an error player.exe has stopped working I tried looking for answers and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500108/genymotion-virtual-device-opens-and-disappears-immediately) however, I had the open gl 2.0 problem earlier for which i updated my graphics driver my motherboard is asus P5G41C - M LX. I updated the drivers for windows 7, and the open gl 2.0 problem has stopped, but still its not working.

The emulator starts with a blank screen and the error pops up saying player.exe has stopped working. I have genymotion version 2.0.3 which comes bundled with the oracle virtual box 4.2.12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

actual problem are in your graphic card.please properly update graphic card with your manufacture website or update vai windows system.

Last . checked "virtual device path" if path are not set than show this problem  & Clean cache in genymotion.

Hope problem are solved

Answer (score 4):

Try to open virtualbox and run that specific Genymotion VM. 
If Virtualbox does not complain about VT-X and Android boots without problems, you can wipe VT-X from the list of possible causes of your issue.

Use logfile quotes of latest boot attempt (Clear Cache in Genymotion settings) to determine the problem.

On my x200 (Win 8) I had problems with an old graphic driver: Intel series 4 Express (GM45). Since Intel does not offer official drivers, i had to

a) modify the inf file to enable installation in Windows 8

b) allow installation of unsigned drivers

Comment: I had the same problem with the graphic card (Intel series 4 Express) and I followed this instructions to install the updated drivers. (http://pattispathways.com/2013/07/06/finally-a-fix-for-windows-8-opengl-error/), and now it works!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, my laptop is a Sony Vaio VPCEB17FL runs over Win7x64, to solve it:

1. Enable VT-x (Intel).
2. Update your video drivers

Comment: How to enable VT-x? any guideline or links

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a recent computer with up to date graphic drivers.
By the way, Genymotion requires OpenGL 2.0.

If your computer is over 6 years old and doesn't have a dedicated graphic card, like an old laptop, your chances of running Genymotion properly will shrink dramatically.

Desktop computers will have less hardware incompatibilities.