# Emulator opens and disappeared on Android Studio

Tags: android, emulation

I am facing this problem when i am starting my emulator from android studio avd manager. it shows the list of my virtual devices. now when i start the emulator. it shows progress to opens and disappeared in a second without throwing/showing any error.
i am using latest android studio version. 
system config : Intel core 2 duo 
ram : 6 GB

is this problem cause of system config? Please write your answer and feel free to ask.

Comment: i am using win-8. I haven't checked on linux.

Comment: @Sourabhsharma did you downloaded your system image of android os. If not go to sdk manager and download it.

Comment: yes @SaurabhBandhari i have downloaded

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues (the simulator progress would open then disappear) on my Mac El Capital. Downloading the latest HAXM and RE-INSTALLING it fixed.

Download link: https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the video drivers and solved : 
1. emulator problem 
2. genymotion "player.exe stopped working" problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) replace for default Android Emulator.

Comment: thanks Louis, when i start genymotion it shows the error 'player.exe has stopped working'

Comment: refer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20727538/genymotion-player-exe-stoped-working

Comment: I updated the video drivers and solved :  1. emulator problem 2. genymotion "player.exe stopped working" problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are some various ways to solve this kind of problems:
-> after restarting android studio, if u are facing same problem then try below ones.

1. kill the adb server through adb shell and then start adb and then launch your emulator.

2.First uncheck Enable ADB Integration and launch emulator and then check Enable ADB Integration.

3.launch your adb and emulator by Debug app from run .

4.maintain the targetSdkVersion corresponding to your emulator

5.uninstall existing emulators and create new one. 
delete your adb application and and download new one.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because I had many (20) devices saved in my AVD with lots of memory allocated to each (1GB) and my laptop was lower than normal on memory itself.

I cleared out the devices in AVD and started over and it began to work normally again.